# iptables owner module not found - match error "No chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, firewall

This is a fresh copy of ubuntu on my nVidia Jetson Nano, and I am trying to add the following rule to block network access for user 1001.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j DROP
```

I get the following error:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Here is what I tried that works(YES) and does not work(NOT)

1. YES - Remove the match criteria and replace with some other condition like source or target
2. YES - On another similar installation on raspberry pi
3. NOT - Change chain or target to INPUT or ACCEPT etc..
4. NOT - Use a different user
5. NOT - Try using user names instead of user ID
6. NOT - Try a different match like --gid-owner
7. NOT - Flushing the tables, restarting the PC etc
8. NOT - Removed the `! -o lo` from the command above

This is beyond me, I really have tried a lot of things and read through a number of posts with the same error - most of the times they are trying to do something complex - yet this is simple (and works on my other installation!). Any thoughts on how to understand this would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Based on comment below, here are the outputs:

```
grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

> grep: /boot/config-4.9.140-tegra: No such file or directory

I manually checked for the file and there's no file that starts with config-XX in the boot folder. Additionally:

```
iptables -m owner --help
```

> Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is.
>
> ....
>
> owner match options:
>
> [!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]      Match local UID
>
> [!] --gid-owner groupid[-groupid]    Match local GID
>
> [!] --socket-exists                  Match if socket exists

Comment: After further investigation it seems that the netfilter match extension might not be available to be. I am not sure how to check this, and how to install it. Help here would be great!

Comment: You an check the available match modules of your kernel with `grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH /boot/config-$(uname -r)`. To test if the specific module is usable you could use `iptables -m owner --help`.

Comment: grep: /boot/config-4.9.140-tegra: No such file or directory - that's the error I get. I am on 18.04. However, when running the second command I see the option that I need - but with a message on the top that says -  " Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is."

Answer (score 2):

`sudo modinfo ipt_owner`

Should return information about the module if it's loaded or not.
In most desktop / server distros it comes compiled into the kernel and would be listed here.

you can try loading it with
`sudo modprobe ipt_owner`

but if it is like I suspect your distribution doesn't bundle it.
Possibly you are not using a "official" Ubuntu release but one built from ubuntu sources by some third party?

Then you need to download your kernel sources and compile the module yourself to support your use-case

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful. Yes, the module is not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.140-tegra. Can you guide me to how I can "download kernel sources and compile the module myself" - I am not sure what that means.